# Best codec for voice and mechanical keyboard clicks?

Tags: audio

I need to make videos where the audio incorporates only voice and occasional keyboard clicks (loud Cherry MX Blue keys).

My question: what's the best audio codec to choose for this? A mono 128mbps MP3 gives me 1 minute = 1 mb. A variable MP3 encoding set to 'low' gives me half that. But are there codecs which take up even less space and don't result in degraded quality?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Opus has been designed to cover very low bitrate encoding up to high quality sound.  Definitely worth a try and a patent and royalty free codec.